# Create table with primary key using jOOQ

Tags: java, sqlite, jooq

jOOQ has CREATE TABLE syntax as stated [in the documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.5/manual/sql-building/ddl-statements/create-statement/):

```
create.createTable(AUTHOR)
      .column(AUTHOR.ID, SQLDataType.INTEGER)
      .column(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, SQLDataType.VARCHAR.length(50))
      .column(AUTHOR_LAST_NAME, SQLDataType.VARCHAR.length(50))
      .execute();
```

I'm wondering how to define which column belongs to the primary key? So is there a way in jOOQ to create a CREATE TABLE statement with PRIMARY KEY information?

I'm specifically interested in a solution for SQLite, which doesn't have syntax to add the primary key afterwards, so I think in worst case I have to go to a DB specific solution?

Comment: A quick look at the manual and javadoc seems to suggest this isn't available.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't look like there is any way... I suspect I have to create the CREATE TABLE SQL string myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature has been implemented for jOOQ 3.8: [#4050](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4050).

```
create.createTable(AUTHOR)
      .column(AUTHOR.ID, SQLDataType.INTEGER)
      .column(AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME, SQLDataType.VARCHAR.length(50))
      .column(AUTHOR_LAST_NAME, SQLDataType.VARCHAR.length(50))
      .constraints(
           constraint("PK_AUTHOR").primaryKey(AUTHOR.ID)
      )
      .execute();
```

Since jOOQ 3.6 ([#3338](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3338)), you can also use the `ALTER TABLE` statement to add a constraint after creating the table:

```
create.alterTable(AUTHOR)
      .add(constraint("PK_AUTHOR").primaryKey(AUTHOR.ID))
      .execute();
```

Comment: @JaysonMinard: Indeed. Due for early Q2 2016

Comment: According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5062), this feature has been re-targetted for 3.9. Sad. :(

Comment: @SPoage: Indeed. It's one of the trickiest DDL elements, due to lack of standardisation among databases... There wasn't enough time to make sure we get this right for 3.8